# Можно ли запустить приложение для просмотра фильмов?

Tags: android, google-play

Я хочу запустить приложение(android) для онлайн просмотра фильмов(в основном пиратский контент) но вроде бы гугл без вопросов и предупреждений сразу же блокирует подобное. Если ли какой нибудь выход? Что то вроде страницы для правообладателей как на многих подобных сайтах.

Comment: Ваше приложение будет заблокировано когда гугл получит претензию от правообладателя. И боюсь поддержке гугла будет абсолютно всё равно есть у вас форма для правообладателей или нет. Если жалоба будет, то приложение как минимум заблокируют, а при рецидиве могут и весь аккаунт заблокировать и потом и Ваши новые аккаунты сразу блокировать.

Comment: не заливать такое на `google play market`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да это возможно но при заливание в Google Play укажите только страны где нету закон про авторские права или там где это не так за ним смотрят например: Россия, Таджикистан и другие страны снг. Но вы при этотм должны где нибудь в приложение указать через какой сайт фильмы были скачаны (а лучше скачивайте через торрент и укажите это) так вас не могут осудить за пиратство.
А самое главное через ваше приложение не должно быть возможности скачивать фильмы.

У меня тоже есть приложение такого типа

Comment: В России за этим смотрят уже и пиратский контент закрывают.